# Is there a difference between using or not a colon after symbol name definitions in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

2 forms in constant declaration:

```
len equ 2
len: equ 2
```

Are they the same?

If not then what is the advantage or disadvantage of each declaration form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The functional difference between these two:

```
len  equ 2
len: equ 2
```

is no difference at all. As stated on the [NASM doc page](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html):

> NASM places no restrictions on white space within a line: labels may have white space before them, or instructions may have no space before them, or anything. **The colon after a label is also optional.**
>
> (Note that this means that if you intend to code lodsb alone on a line, and type lodab by accident, then that's still a valid source line which does nothing but define a label. Running NASM with the command-line option -w+orphan-labels will cause it to warn you if you define a label alone on a line without a trailing colon.)

Comment: I want to know the difference between "len equ 2" and "len: equ 2". Sorry if my question is unclear, i changed it. Please excuse my english.

Comment: Sorry, @Linh, I misunderstood the original question to mean "what's the difference between equ and db?". Going back and rereading, the fault was clearly mine, not yours.

Comment: @Linh, rather than waste a perfectly good answer (albeit to the wrong question), I've posted the original one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006711/whats-the-difference-between-equ-and-db-in-nasm, to the _right_ question, if you're interested :-)