# What's the difference between equ and db in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, compile-time-constant

```
len:  equ  2
len:  db   2
```

Are they the same, producing a label that can be used instead of `2`? If not, then what is the advantage or disadvantage of each declaration form? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The first is `equate`, similar to C's:

```
#define len 2
```

in that it doesn't actually allocate any space in the final code, it simply sets the `len` symbol to be equal to 2. Then, when you use `len` later on in your source code, it's the same as if you're using the constant `2`.

The second is `define byte`, similar to C's:

```
int len = 2;
```

It *does* actually allocate space, one byte in memory, stores a `2` there, and sets `len` to be the *address* of that byte.

Here's some pseudo-assembler code that shows the distinction:

```
line   addr   code       label   instruction
----   ----   --------   -----   -----------
   1   0000                      org    1234h
   2   1234              elen    equ    2
   3   1234   02         dlen    db     2
   4   1235   44 02 00           mov    ax,     elen
   5   1238   44 34 12           mov    ax,     dlen
```

Line 1 simply sets the assembly address to be `1234h`, to make it easier to explain what's happening.

In line 2, no code is generated, the assembler simply loads `elen` into the symbol table with the value `2`. Since no code has been generated, the address does not change.

Then, when you use it on line 4, it loads that value into the register.

Line 3 shows that `db` is different, it actually allocates some space (one byte) and stores the value in that space. It then loads `dlen` into the symbol table but gives it the value of that address `1234h` rather than the constant value `2`.

When you later use `dlen` on line 5, you get the address, which you would have to dereference to get the actual value `2`.

Comment: NASM 2.10.09 ELF output nitpicks: 1) "no data is generated": true for the executable after linking and RAM space, but the object file that NASM generates does contain the symbol data. 2) "similar to C's #define":  in a sense, but `equ` does generate a symbol, which could be used by other object files with `extern` and without including the macro in those files. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33148242/895245

Comment: Good points, @Ciro, I thought the meaning was obvious from context but, to be certain, I've changed data to code to ensure clarity. As to the `#define`, similarity isn't necessarily equality but I'll try to clarify that as well :-)

Comment: So, indeed does db generate global variables...? Instead is there a easier method to store string in frame stacks? (other than mov dword [rsp] 'foo'  ;because storing longer strings become difficult)

Comment: `len: db 2` is more like `char len = 2`, not `int`.  For `int` you'd use `dd`.  (Or `dw` if you're targeting a 16-bit ABI where `int` is `int16_t`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes wouldn't `unsigned char len` be more appropriate?

Comment: so `equ` would result in immediate addressing while `db`, in direct addressing?

Comment: @FirstUser: It would be equally appropriate, so would `signed char len = 2;`.  In asm, signedness is about what instructions you use on the value; `db` doesn't imply signed or unsigned.  (If you'd used `db -2`, then in C terms it would definitely be a `signed char`.)  You might later reuse the same storage for an unsigned value, but that would be like a C union.)  C `char` is either signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation; mainstream x86 ABIs have signed `char`, although compilers will still treat `char` vs. `signed char` mismatches as worth warning about for portability.

Comment: @FirstUser: re: addressing: there is no addressing until you use them.  If I did `mov eax, [rdi + len]` with the EQU version, that would be a displacement to go with a base regsiter.  Or with DB, that would use the symbol address as the displacement, RDI indexing a byte array.   If I did `mov eax, [rbx + rdi*len]`, that would only work with the assemble-time constant EQU, becoming the scale factor.  In NASM syntax, `mov edi, len` is an immediate operand either way, either the value `2` or the symbol address.  To get `2` into a register, though, yes, `mov eax, len` vs. `movzx eax, byte [len]`

Answer (score 9):

**Summary**

NASM 2.10.09 ELF output:

- `db` does not have any magic effects: it simply outputs bytes directly to the output object file.

  If those bytes happen to be in front of a symbol, the symbol will point to that value when the program starts.

  If you are on the text section, your bytes will get executed.

  Weather you use `db` or `dw`, etc. that does not specify the size of the symbol: the `st_size` field of the symbol table entry is not affected.
- `equ` makes the symbol in the current line have `st_shndx == SHN_ABS` magic value in its symbol table entry.

  Instead of outputting a byte to the current object file location, it outputs it to the `st_value` field of the symbol table entry.

All else follows from this.

To understand what that really means, you should first understand [the basics of the ELF standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30648229/895245) and [relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30507725/895245).

**SHN_ABS theory**

`SHN_ABS` tells the linker that:

- relocation is not to be done on this symbol
- the `st_value` field of the symbol entry is to be used as a value directly

Contrast this with "regular" symbols, in which the value of the symbol is a memory address instead, and must therefore go through relocation.

Since it does not point to memory, `SHN_ABS` symbols can be effectively removed from the executable by the linker by inlining them.

But they are still regular symbols on object files and *do* take up memory there, and could be shared amongst multiple files if global.

**Sample usage**

```
section .data
    x: equ 1
    y: db 2
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov al, x
    ; al == 1
    mov al, [y]
    ; al == 2
```

Note that since the symbol `x` contains a literal value, no dereference `[]` must be done to it like for `y`.

If we wanted to use `x` from a C program, we'd need something like:

```
extern char x;
printf("%d", &x);
```

and set on the asm:

```
global x
```

**Empirical observation of generated output**

We can observe what we've said before with:

```
nasm -felf32 -o equ.o equ.asm
ld -melf_i386 -o equ equ.o
```

Now:

```
readelf -s equ.o
```

contains:

```
Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
  4: 00000001     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS x
  5: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 y
```

`Ndx` is `st_shndx`, so we see that `x` is `SHN_ABS` while `y` is not.

Also see that `Size` is `0` for `y`: `db` in no way told `y` that it was a single byte wide. We could simply add two `db` directives to allocate 2 bytes there.

And then:

```
objdump -dr equ
```

gives:

```
08048080 <_start>:
 8048080:       b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
 8048082:       a0 88 90 04 08          mov    0x8049088,%al
```

So we see that `0x1` was inlined into instruction, while `y` got the value of a relocation address `0x8049088`.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64.

**Docs**

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4:

> EQU defines a symbol to a given constant value: when EQU is used, the source line must contain a label. The action of EQU is to define the given label name to the value of its (only) operand. This definition is absolute, and cannot change later. So, for example,

```
message         db      'hello, world' 
msglen          equ     $-message
```

> defines msglen to be the constant 12. msglen may not then be redefined later. This is not a preprocessor definition either: the value of msglen is evaluated once, using the value of $ (see section 3.5 for an explanation of $) at the point of definition, rather than being evaluated wherever it is referenced and using the value of $ at the point of reference.

**See also**

Analogous question for GAS: [Difference between .equ and .word in ARM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624155/difference-between-equ-and-word-in-arm-assembly) `.equiv` seems to be the closes GAS equivalent.

Comment: As the manual alludes to, you can use `$` in equates which can result in a symbol much like putting a label. That is, `label:` and `label equ $` are almost exactly the same. (Equates are ignored for the local label mechanism however.) The example with `$-message` is the difference of two symbols though so it is evaluated as a scalar number.

Answer (score 8):

**equ**: preprocessor time. analogous to #define but most assemblers are lacking an #undef, and can't have anything but an atomic constant of fixed number of bytes on the right hand side, so floats, doubles, lists are not supported with most assemblers' equ directive.

**db**: compile time. the value stored in db is stored in the binary output by the assembler at a specific offset. equ allows you define constants that normally would need to be either hardcoded, or require a mov operation to get. db allows you to have data available in memory before the program even starts.

Here's a nasm demonstrating db:

```
; I am a 16 byte object at offset 0.
    db '----------------'

; I am a 14 byte object at offset 16
; the label foo makes the assembler remember the current 'tell' of the 
; binary being written.
foo:
    db 'Hello, World!', 0

; I am a 2 byte filler at offset 30 to help readability in hex editor.
    db ' .'

; I am a 4 byte object at offset 16 that the offset of foo, which is 16(0x10).
    dd foo
```

[image]

An equ can only define a constant up to the largest the assembler supports

example of equ, along with a few common limitations of it.

```
; OK
ZERO equ 0

; OK(some assemblers won't recognize \r and will need to look up the ascii table to get the value of it).
CR equ 0xD
; OK(some assemblers won't recognize \n and will need to look up the ascii table to get the value of it).
LF equ 0xA

; error: bar.asm:2: warning: numeric constant 102919291299129192919293122 -
; does not fit in 64 bits
; LARGE_INTEGER equ 102919291299129192919293122

; bar.asm:5: error: expression syntax error
; assemblers often don't support float constants, despite fitting in
; reasonable number of bytes. This is one of the many things
; we take for granted in C, ability to precompile floats at compile time
; without the need to create your own assembly preprocessor/assembler.
; PI equ 3.1415926 

; bar.asm:14: error: bad syntax for EQU
; assemblers often don't support list constants, this is something C
; does support using define, allowing you to define a macro that
; can be passed as a single argument to a function that takes multiple.
; eg
; #define RED 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
; glVertex4f(RED);
; #undef RED
;RED equ 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

the resulting binary has no bytes at all because equ does not pollute the image; all references to an equ get replaced by the right hand side of that equ.

Comment: Equates may be similar to defines but NASM does have `%define` (and `%xdefine` and `%assign`) also.