# Difference between .equ and .word in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, directive, cortex-m

I am curious - What is the difference between `.equ` and `.word` directives in ARM assembly, when defining constants?

Answer (score 27):

**`.equ`** is like `#define` in C:

```
#define bob 10
.equ bob, 10
```

**`.word`** is like `unsigned int` in C:

```
unsigned int ted;
ted: 
.word 0
```

Or initialized with a value:

```
unsigned int alice = 42;
alice:
.word 42
```

Comment: and it has nothing to do with ARM it is true for most/all platforms supported by gnu assembler and other assemblers with those directives

Comment: Nitpicking :-) 1) `.word is like unsigned int in C`: but it does not set `st_size` as most C compilers, and it can be used anywhere, e.g. on the text section to generate code. 2) `.equ is like #define`: but it also generates an ABS symbol || More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33157659/895245

Comment: was just trying to relate to something the OP might understand, like but not exactly like, similar perhaps a better word than like?

Comment: Also note that `.word` does *not* create a symbol. So it is rather like `malloc()`, imho. It just reserves a word of anonymous space wherever it appears. You can actually use it to generate instructions if you feel like puzzling together the bits of the opcodes.

Comment: @Kamajii doesn't .word always allocate 4 bytes of space?

Answer (score 4):

.word is a directive that allocates a word-sized amount of storage space (memory) in that location. It can additionally have that location initialized with a given value.

.equ is more like a C preprocessor #define statement - it gets substituted in any subsequent code.

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/Equ.html#Equ

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/Word.html#Word

This is not actually ARM-specific, but applies to all gas targets.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that you can't use `.word` to initialize variables in RAM...you need something at runtime to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the accepted answer (written by old_timer) `label: .word value` is like assigning a value to that label. I just want to add that **you can assign multiple values to the same label just like an array**, as the following:

```
g_pfnVectors:
  .word  _estack
  .word  Reset_Handler
  .word  NMI_Handler
  .word  HardFault_Handler
  .word  MemManage_Handler
  ...
```

The previous example has been taken from a STM32 MCU official startup file. This is exactly the machanism to initialize the *NVIC*.
So `g_pfnVectors` label got multiple values assigned (as an array, where the values are aligned next to each other in the memory so to say).

Answer (score -1):

NASM 2.10.09 ELF output:

- `.word` is simple: it outputs 2 bytes to the object file no matter where we are.

  Consequences of this:

  - if `.word` is after a symbol `x:`, `x` will point to those bytes
  - if `.word` is in the text segment, those bytes might get executed

  It has absolutely no other side effect. In particular, it does *not* set the `st_size` field of the symbol table entry (e.g. `int` often == 4 bytes), which is something sensible compilers should do. You need the `.size x, 2` directive for that.
- `.equ` does *two* things:

  1. updates a macro-like variable
  2. the last time you call it, it generates a symbol with `st_shndx == SHN_ABS` and the given value

  Sample code:

  ```
  .text

      .equ x, 123
      mov $x, %eax
      /* eax == 123 */

      .equ x, 456
      mov $x, %eax
      /* eax == 456 */
  ```

  Now:

  ```
  as --32 -o main.o main.S
  objdump -Sr main.o
  ```

  Gives:

  ```
  00000000 <.text>:
    0:   b8 7b 00 00 00          mov    $0x7b,%eax
    5:   b8 c8 01 00 00          mov    $0x1c8,%eax
  ```

  which confirms the macro-like effect, and:

  ```
  readelf -s main.o
  ```

  contains:

  ```
  Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    4: 000001c8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS x
  ```

  which confirms the `SHN_ABS` effect: a symbol was created, and it could be used from another file by linking if it were global. I have explained this in more detail at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33148242/895245

  The situation is analogous for NASM's `equ`, except that the NASM version can only be used once per symbol.

  `.set` and the equals sign `=` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175248/is-there-a-difference-between-equals-sign-assignment-x-1-and-equ-x-1-or)) are the same as `.equ`.

  You should also look into `.equiv` https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Equiv.html , which prevents redefinition.