# Is there a difference between equals sign assignment "x = 1" and ".equ x, 1" or ".set x, 1" in GNU Gas assembly?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

E.g.:

```
a = 1
```

and:

```
.equ a, 1
```

and:

```
.set a, 1
```

all produce the same output byte-by-byte upon:

```
as --32 main.S
```

according to `cmp`.

I know that `.equ` and `.set` do the same thing according to the documentation of `.equ`: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Equ.html :

> It is synonymous with `.set'.

and I know what `.equ` does from [Difference between .equ and .word in ARM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624155/difference-between-equ-and-word-in-arm-assembly)

So what about `=`? Is it the same as the other two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same.

After grepping the documentation source, I've found the section that confirms it https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Setting-Symbols.html

> A symbol can be given an arbitrary value by writing a symbol, followed by an equals sign `=', followed by an expression (see Expressions). This is equivalent to using the .set directive.